# JavaFX : fx:id proofing

Tags: java, javafx

Entering `fx:id`'s manually across controllers and FXML files and late binding are a potential source of errors, fragilising code robustness (my personal opinion).
On the other hand, it offers flexibility.

Is there a way of proofing the binding and identifying errors before revealing them at runtime, or is this the "by design" workflow and you have to make do and just be careful while coding ?

**edit :** 
I am using Eclipse with e(fx)clipse, and Gluon Scene Builder

Comment: If you set the `fx:controller` attribute on your root element, some IDEs (IntelliJ, for example) will use it to cross-check `fx:id` values to `@FXML`-annotated fields.

Comment: @sillyfly This also works with the latest version of Eclipse. You could also use `assert btnLogin != null : "fx:id=\"btnLogin\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'LoginView.fxml'.";` in the `initialize` method of you controller.

Comment: @sillyfly I tried it on Eclipse and I have no warning through intellisense when I reference a control in the controller that is not present in the FXML (referencing that controller)

Comment: What kind of logic would you use to validate the fxml??? There are other uses of `fx:id` than injecting the value to the controller and a user may accidentally annotate a field with `@FXML` evne though it's written to from the controller class itself. Both do not result in errors, however it would be likely that validation would fail for them...

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there is no real "proof" like the `javac` which would complain. JavaFx to too dynmaic for this. The best thing you can do is adding the controller to your FXML file like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.geometry.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<ScrollPane xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" 
    xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="com.myapp.MyController">
    <content>
        ...
    </content>
</ScrollPane>
```

This then allows `Eclipse` or `IntelliJ` (thx @silifly) to show you warning about elements which have not been binded to you controller. Bu this will not tell if the injection which is performed by the `FXMLLoader` was successful. You then could check during the initialization phase if your element has been injected correctly.

```
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;

public class MyController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private Button btnLogin;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        assert btnLogin != null : "fx:id=\"btnLogin\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'MyView.fxml'.";
    }
}
```

Those are the two facilities which I know and use a lot to check if everything has been setup correctly.

Edit:

I just saw that [you don't need to implement the interface anymore](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/Initializable.html) you can just write

```
@FXML
public void initialize() {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Note that not implementing the interface and just using a method called `initialize` introduces another place the compiler cannot check for typos....

Comment: I did exactly that and I have no warning in Eclipse. Am I missing something here ?

Comment: You will not see any errors in the "Problems" tab, you need to open the FXML file then it will mark all elements with warnings that they are not linked to to controller